# I want to be able to redirect the user to a specific link in a WebView

Tags: android, redirect, webview

Need some advice. I want to be able to redirect the user to a specific link in WebView. Example: we go to the first link and if it directs us to "google.com" then we will have to direct the user to "http://test.com". I made an implementation, put a redirect in shouldOverrideUrlLoading, however, after SplashScreen-loading image done its work, a white background appears and that's it. At the same time, if you remove the code for redirection, then after performing its work, the SplashScreen - loading image, the first link opens and the page from the Internet is displayed correctly. How do I redirect to other pages after opening the first one?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView webView;
private final String TAG = "MainActivity";
   
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("http://test/start");
    new TaskForRedirecting().execute();

}


public class TaskForRedirecting extends AsyncTask<Boolean, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Boolean... booleans) {
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d(TAG, "Start loading here");
                WebViewClient webViewClient = new WebViewClient() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                        if (url.contains("google.com")) {
                            view.loadUrl("http://test1.com");
                            return false;
                        } else if (url.contains("yahoo.com")) {
                            view.loadUrl("http://test2.com");
                            return false;
                        } else {
                        }
                        return true;
                    }


                    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                        if (request.getUrl().toString() == "google.com") {
                            view.loadUrl("http://test1.com");
                            view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
                            return false;
                        } else if (request.getUrl().toString() == "yahoo.com") {
                            view.loadUrl("http://test2.com");
                            return false;
                        }
                        return true;
                    }

                };

                webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
                Log.d(TAG, "Do in background: APP is Working!!!");
            }
        });
        return false;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean success) {
        success = false;
        if (success) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "App is under maintenance!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        } else {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Let's start to work!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();

        }
        Log.d(TAG, "upload - final! ");
    }
}
```

}

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

long Delay = 6000;
private final String TAG = "SplashScreenActivity";
private WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

    new SplashScreen().execute();
}

public class SplashScreen extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void...voids) {

        Timer RunSplash = new Timer();

        TimerTask ShowSplash = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                finish();

                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        };

        RunSplash.schedule(ShowSplash, Delay);
        Log.d(TAG, "ShowSplash - final! ");

        return null;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: are you using https or http urls?

Comment: i am using http

Comment: Check out the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation needs to change a bit, we don't need to set the webview client inside an AsyncTask, instead, we can set it directly but it should be set before we call `loadurl`.

I have removed the `asynctask`, and set the client in `onCreate` method before calling `loadUrl`.

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        WebViewClient webViewClient = new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if (url.contains("google.com")) {
                    view.loadUrl("http://test1.com");
                    return true;
                } else if (url.contains("yahoo.com")) {
                    view.loadUrl("http://test2.com");
                    return true;
                } 
                return false;
            }


            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                if (request.getUrl().toString() == "google.com") {
                    view.loadUrl("http://test1.com");
                    return true;
                } else if (request.getUrl().toString() == "yahoo.com") {
                    view.loadUrl("http://test2.com");
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

        };
        webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
        webView.loadUrl("http://test/start");
    }
```

**UPDATE**

Please check out the [shouldOverrideUrlLoading Doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest)), You should return `true` when you want to cancel the current load, so when you want to load a different `URL`, then return `true` else return false to continue the current load. **Returning `false` means the URL which is being loaded to the webview will continue, your custom URL will not be loaded.**

Comment: Unfortunally, still white background, without redirecting.

Comment: @V.M. fixed bug, please check out, and try to put valid URL instead of `http://test1.com` and other dummies. e.g. Put `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia`

Comment: Rahat, thank you for your active help. I have read the documentation and see two options for working with shouldOverrideUrlLoading :1) when we want the page (URL) to open inside our application, we use return false 2) when we want the URL to open outside of our application, using any browser, we use return true. I want my links to open inside the app, so I use return false. On your advice, I changed the value to true, but the links didn't open.

Comment: @V.M. can I expect the answer to be accepted, and get an upvote.

Comment: unfortunately, your answer did not give a solution to the question, if you still have thoughts on how to make a redirect, I am ready to listen